# Advice for a high-end Ubuntu-friendly laptop?

Tags: hardware, graphics, laptop, compatibility

Since I figure the collective computer knowledge on these forums is pretty high, I was wondering if someone could give me advice for buying a new laptop.

I'm looking for something with:

-High linux compatibility

-Sandy bridge i7 processor

-Low end but better-than-integrated graphics (AMD preferred, since NVIDIA Optimus has LInux issues)

-Blu-ray drive

-Not a Mac

I've been looking around at Lenovo and Asus, but I haven't found anything yet that fits all of these requirements. Anybody have experience/suggestions?

I'm not a hardcore gamer, but I would like to be able to play games/experiment with graphics programming on this, it's more than just an internet machine.

Answer (score 2):

[System76](https://www.system76.com/index.php?cPath=28) has some great offers that might be up your alley.

Or, you could keep an eye open over at [DealNews](http://dealnews.com/c49/Computers/Laptops/)

Comment: Dealnews link doesn't seem to have much - a bunch of touch screen, around 1000x700 low res screens without IPS, without cd writer. System76's Have non touch and all those useful features, at competitive price - unless the stories of bad build quality are true.?

Answer (score 2):

The System76 Pangolin Performance meets each of your requests, except Blu-Ray.  Though you should be able to find a replacement optical drive fairly easily.

http://www.system76.com/product_info.php?cPath=28&products_id=118

Answer (score 0):

Try to dig into the lists of Linux-compatible laptops with i7-2XXXQM CPUs on this web page: https://linux-hardware.org/?view=search&name=Core+i7-2%25QM&typeid=cpu

You need to click on the particular CPU and then select a laptop/probe to see hardware specs.

[image]

I'm the author of this project, feel free to ask any questions in comments!

Answer (score 0):

I would search among

- enterprise class laptop computers
- Intel i5 or i7 CPU, often better compatibility with linux drivers if 1-3 years old,

  - refurbished (second hand) computers sold by companies, that give you a guarantee for at least 6 months. Search the internet with the search string 'enterprise class laptop' (without quotes) and look for links in your country (or even better, your region or town). It helps if you translate the search string to your language.
  - new enough,

    - Intel i7 generation 2 or newer
    - Intel i5 generation 3 or newer

  In my country several refurbished computers with Intel generation 4 CPUs are sold nowadays, and also some computers with generation 5 CPUs  (April 2018).
- at least 4 GiB RAM, better with 8 GiB RAM.
- it might help with nvidia graphics (but some models can be difficult with linux),
- integrated Intel graphics generation 3 or 4 or newer should be good enough (depending on what you need).
- monitor resolution (typical examples)

  ```
   - 'basic':     1366x768
   - 'better':    1600x900
   - 'full HD':   1920x1080
  ```

  You need more horsepower to play video with higher resolution.